# Generating the report in .doc format using PHP using data queried from MySQL DB hosted on Linux

Tags: php, mysql, export, .doc

I need to export the queried data from MySQL db running on Linux platform to .doc and other formats (.e.g PDF). For this I need a class like FPDF with good documentation. 
Already tried to explore a couple of classes like PHPWord, MsDocGenerator et al. 
However the non-availability of good amount of documenation of these classes and the available methods therein, I am finding it difficult to export the reports in .doc format.

Any pointer to well documented classes and may be good tutorials on their usage, would be a great help to me.

(PS> I am not using any PHP framework to build this application. The dev and deployment environment would consist of PHP 5.x/MySQL/Apache on Linux. Therefore available solutions like http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/ will not be useful for as pre-requisite to them is adaption of Zend framework)

Thanks, Satya

Comment: I've used PHPWord before and didn't find the documentation too bad, did you see this - http://phpword.codeplex.com/releases/view/49543

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising: http://www.phpdocx.com/

Well documented, established, several formats.